# How to dynamically change the classname of already existing elements in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a simple memory game and I want to indicate that the player guessed the correct/incorrect answer by modifying the classnames of existing elements such that they flash green or red, I am currently just printing 'CORRECT' and 'WRONG' to the console.

Here is a function that renders the elements I want to flash green/red:

```js
  const renderMajorSegment = (musicKey, index) => {
    let arc = calculateArc(outerRadius, innerRadius, musicKey.segmentMetadata.startAngle, musicKey.segmentMetadata.endAngle);
    let [arcCenterX, arcCenterY] = arc.centroid();

    return <g className={`circle-segment ${musicKey.segmentMetadata.majorCircle.isVisible ? 'isVisible': ''}`} 
              key={index}>
            <path 
              d={arc.apply()} // apply() is needed to generate the string that goes into the 'd' attribute
            />
            <text x={arcCenterX} y={arcCenterY} transform={`rotate(15, ${arcCenterX}, ${arcCenterY})`}>
              {abbreviateKeyFromChord(musicKey.chords[0])}
            </text>
          </g>
  }
```

And here is the main part of my functional components:

```js
  return (
    <div className='circle-of-fifths-container'>
      <svg
        height={diameter*1.1}
        width={diameter*1.1}>
        <g className='circle-container' transform={`translate(${diameter/2 + 25},${diameter/2 + 25}) rotate(-15)`}>
          <circle r={outerRadius} className='base-circle'/>
          <g className='outer-circle-segments-container'>
            {musicKeysObject.map((musicKey, index) => renderMajorSegment(musicKey, index))}
          </g>
          <g className='inner-circle-segments-container'>
            {musicKeysObject.map((musicKey, index) => renderMinorSegment(musicKey, index))}
          </g>
          {mode === READY && 
            <g id='play-button-container' onMouseUp={startRound}>
              <circle r={innerRadius2} id='play-button'/>
              <text id='play-button-text' transform='rotate(15)'>PLAY GAME</text>
            </g>}
        </g>
      </svg>
      {mode === PLAYING &&
        <input placeholder='Your answer' onKeyDown={handleUserInput}></input>
      }
    </div>
  )
```

I haven't really tried anything yet, I'm just thinking about the problem and coming up with some solutions on how to approach it.

My first idea was to add a parameter to the `renderMajorSegment()` function which could accept a string based on the correct/wrong answer and then change the classname according to that.

After some googling, I found that I could store something in state and then modify the class of the elements based on the value of the state. In this case, I would modify the value of the state and I would just be able to reference the state value in the `renderSegmentMajor()` function and do something similar to what I've already done with the `isVisible` value.

This is my function that will handle the logic and cause the classname changes to occur (when the user submit an answer):

```js
  const handleUserInput = (event) => {
    var index;
    if (hiddenSegment.major) {
      index = 0;
    } else {
      index = 5;
    }

    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      if (event.target.value === abbreviateKeyFromChord(hiddenSegment.chords[index])) {
        console.log('CORRECT');
        // Set both major and minor circles to true
        // 1 will already be true so it makes no difference, sets the non-visible one to true
        hiddenSegment.segmentMetadata.majorCircle.isVisible = true;
        hiddenSegment.segmentMetadata.minorCircle.isVisible = true;

        // Modify the css classes to make the segments go green

        startRound();
      } else {
        // Modify the css classes to make the segments go red
        console.log('WRONG');
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was correct in thinking that `useState` was a good method to achieve the functionality I wanted here.

Here is my `useState` hook and the 2 values that I can use for this hook:

```js
const CORRECT = 'correct';
const WRONG = 'wrong';
const [userAnswer, setUserAnswer] = useState(null);
```

I can then modify the classNames based on the value of the `useState`. I am using the [classnames utility](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) to make this a bit easier and make my code cleaner

```js
    var segmentClasses = classNames(
      'circle-segment',
      {'isVisible': musicKey.segmentMetadata.majorCircle.isVisible},
      {'correctAnswer': userAnswer === CORRECT},
      {'wrongAnswer': userAnswer === WRONG}
    );

    return <g className={segmentClasses} key={index}>
            <path 
              d={arc.apply()} // apply() is needed to generate the string that goes into the 'd' attribute
            />
            <text x={arcCenterX} y={arcCenterY} transform={`rotate(15, ${arcCenterX}, ${arcCenterY})`}>
              {abbreviateKeyFromChord(musicKey.chords[0])}
            </text>
          </g>
```